# Which of the following is the most efficient

Tags: ruby, loops

If I would like to print x from 0 to 5

```
6.times {|x| p x}

(0..5).each {|x| p x}

0.upto(5) {|x| p x}

for x in 0..5
  p x
end
```

Comment: [`benchmark`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) it! :)

Comment: You'll have to go to the tenth decimal to find out, since `p` takes forever to return.

Comment: Readability and maintainability are generally much more important. Use whichever one makes the most sense in the context of your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[benchmark/ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) is a better tool for this.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("times") { 6.times {|x| } }
  x.report("range iteration") { (0..5).each {|x| } }
  x.report("upto") { 0.upto(5) {|x| } }
  x.report("for") do
    for x in 0..5
    end
  end
end
```

Results on Ruby 2.2.0:

```
Calculating -------------------------------------
               times    88.567k i/100ms
     range iteration    88.519k i/100ms
                upto    86.749k i/100ms
                 for    84.118k i/100ms
-------------------------------------------------
               times      2.093M (± 0.2%) i/s -     10.451M
     range iteration      2.053M (± 0.4%) i/s -     10.268M
                upto      2.103M (± 0.2%) i/s -     10.583M
                 for      1.949M (± 0.2%) i/s -      9.758M
```

Looping an empty body is the better idea here, since the IO time from `p` will likely dwarf the loop iteration times. Result-wise, it's close enough to not matter.

Comment: Thanks I will add **benchmark/ips** to my tool belt Still is the same concept

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use something like **Benchmark**

*The Benchmark module provides methods to measure and report the time used to execute Ruby code.*

```
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark.measure {6.times {|x| p x}}
puts Benchmark.measure {(0..5).each {|x| p x}}
puts Benchmark.measure {0.upto(5) {|x| p x}}
```

and you are going to see a output that looks like

```
1 ) 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000059)
1 ) 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000050)
3 ) 0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000046)
```

now you can read more about **benchmark**  [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)

you can have to try it a couple of many  of times with 1000000.times  to get a good gage, now the results are going to change with every compute and with what else is running on that computer at the time of the test

Comment: I ran your Benchmark for the four methods and obtained the following total times: `[0.000092, 0.000089, 0.000093, 0.000164]`. As you see, the first three are pretty close, but the last `for...end` looks to be quite a bit slower. Just to be sure, let's try it a couple more times: 
`[0.000087, 0.000054, 0.000049, 0.000048]`, `[0.000092, 0.000084, 0.000094, 0.000052]`. The benchmark is spending virtually all it's time waiting for `p` to return, so it's not surprising we are unable to compare the differences in the rest of the code with the given benchmark.